# Set TimeOut for NetworkObject.MapNetworkDrive

Tags: vba, excel

I have some issue on running "NetworkObject.MapNetworkDrive" when searching multiple ServerShare. If ServerShare PC is Online the code work perfectly and its take below than 5 second to respond but when ServerShare PC is offline the code will take 30 second for time out (Default TimeOut). I already set error handling for Run-time Error.

Is there any code to set timeout for 5 second on "NetworkObject.MapNetworkDrive" ?

I have more than 300 ServerShare PC on domain.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub pbCheck_Click()

i = 12
Do
    If Sheets("Update Checker").Cells(2, 8) <> "" And Sheets("Update Checker").Cells(i, 10) <> "" Then
        ServerShare = "\\" & Sheets("Update Checker").Cells(i, 10) & "\c$\Windows\servicing\Packages"
        UserName = Sheets("Update Checker").Cells(i, 10) & "\Administrator"
        Password = "<My_Password>"
    
    Set NetworkObject = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    On Error GoTo ErrCol
    NetworkObject.MapNetworkDrive "", ServerShare, False, UserName, Password
    
    Test = "\\" & Sheets("Update Checker").Cells(i, 10) & "\c$\Windows\servicing\Packages\" & "*" & Sheets("Update Checker").Cells(2, 8) & "*" & ".cat"

    If Dir(Test) <> "" Then
        Sheets("Update Checker").Cells(i, 11) = "OK"
    Else
        Sheets("Update Checker").Cells(i, 11) = "X"
    End If
    
    Set Filename = Nothing
    Set Directory = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing
    
    NetworkObject.RemoveNetworkDrive ServerShare, True, False
    
    Set ShellObject = Nothing
    Set NetworkObject = Nothing
    
End If
NextCol:
    i = i + 1
    Loop Until Sheets("Update Checker").Cells(i, 10) = ""

ErrCol:
Resume NextCol

End Sub
```

My code stuck at `NetworkObject.MapNetworkDrive "", ServerShare, False, UserName, Password` for 30 second if PC is Offline.

Comment: May be use **FSO.FolderExists** to check root folder of the `ServerShare` exist before `MapNetworkDrive`?

Comment: @PatricK thanks for reply, but when I put the `FSO.FolderExists`  before `MapNetworkDrive` the problem still the same. Default TimeOut stuck at `FSO.FolderExists`. Is there any code to set default Runtime / TimeOut for 5 second?

Answer (score 1):

I already solve the problem. I am running PING command to check PC Online or offline, its take 4 second to check each PC and create `Select Case` for Online and Offline PC. Here My Code.

```
Private Sub pbCheck_Click()

i = 12
Do
    If Sheets("Update Checker").Cells(2, 8) <> "" And Sheets("Update Checker").Cells(i, 10) <> "" Then
        ServerShare = "\\" & Sheets("Update Checker").Cells(i, 10) & "\c$\Windows\servicing\Packages"
        UserName = Sheets("Update Checker").Cells(i, 10) & "\Administrator"
        Password = "P@ssw0rd245"

        Set NetworkObject = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
        Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        Test = "\\" & Sheets("Update Checker").Cells(i, 10) & "\c$\Windows\servicing\Packages\" & "*" & Sheets("Update Checker").Cells(2, 8) & "*" & ".cat"

        hostname = Sheets("Update Checker").Cells(i, 10)
        Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Ping = WshShell.Run("ping -n 1 " & hostname, 0, True)
        Select Case Ping
        Case 0

            On Error GoTo ErrCol
            NetworkObject.MapNetworkDrive "", ServerShare, False, UserName, Password

            If Dir(Test) <> "" Then
                Sheets("Update Checker").Cells(i, 11) = "OK"
            Else
                Sheets("Update Checker").Cells(i, 11) = "X"
            End If

            Set Filename = Nothing
            Set Directory = Nothing
            Set FSO = Nothing

            NetworkObject.RemoveNetworkDrive ServerShare, True, False

            Set ShellObject = Nothing
            Set NetworkObject = Nothing

        Case 1
            GoTo NextCol
        End Select
    End If
NextCol:
    i = i + 1
Loop Until Sheets("Update Checker").Cells(i, 10) = ""

Exit Sub

ErrCol:
Resume NextCol

End Sub
```

Comment: You can also add `-w #` where # is milliseconds to wait for a reply to shorten the wait. Depends on your network latency, so test for best safe time.